# Mathematica failing to minimize with parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization

If I run the command

```
Minimize[Sin[x], x]
```

it returns the expected value of -1. However, if I run

```
Minimize[a*Sin[x], x]
```

then I get nothing - Mathematica simply returns the command as the output. Why is this? From the documentation page, the `Minimize` command should be able to handle free variables in the expressions.

Comment: It doesn't know the sign of `a` or if it is bounded. In general the minimum is `-Infinity`. Look at `Minimize[{a*Sin[x], Abs[a] < 5}, {a, x}]`

Comment: Why is it necessary to specify this though? In the documentation, Mathematica is able to minimize a*x^2 + b*x + c as a function of x for arbitrary a, b, c, with different minima depending on the different parameter ranges. I don't understand why this is different.